# Generate random between [0, 1)

Tags: c++, c, random

I want to generate a random float value between 0 and 1 excluding 1, I.e. `[0, 1)`. I've searched a lot but I couldn't find an answer of this. I've tried the following trick however it generates a negative values

```
(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX-1;
```

Comment: You have this tagged as `C++` -- Why not use `<random>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to divide by RAND_MAX including +1. Like this:

```
(double)rand()/((double)RAND_MAX+1);
```

Comment: Not quite. This will produce numbers less than zero.

Comment: This will produce negative values

Comment: seems like I've missed one '('. Fixed

Comment: Thank you. I tried it in a loop of 1000 elements and it shows all less than 1.

Comment: That's not enough (1000). This expression can produce 1 and another value bigger than 1, i.e. `(double)RAND_MAX/(RAND_MAX-1)`

Comment: Thank you all for your collaboration.

Answer (score 2):

You need parentheses to force the right order:

```
(double)rand()/((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
```

Also note, that you need +1, not -1.

Comment: Is the correct answer, although you can remove one of the casts.

Comment: If `RAND_MAX` is 64 bits, `((double)RAND_MAX + 1)` does not increment by one.